# Getting "Command not found" for global node packages

Tags: linux, manjaro, npm

I've installed fkill globally by doing `npm i -g fkill`. I can see it installed when I do `npm list`. It shows only fkill as installed globally when I run `npm list -g --depth=0`. However when I run `fkill` I get "command not found".

Next I ran "npm get prefix" and got "/home/alex/.node_modules". Here is my PATH:

```
/home/alex/.node_modules/bin:/home/alex/.npm-global/bin:/home/alex/.node_modules/bin:/home/alex/.node_modules/lib/node_modules:/home/alex/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/cuda/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

This all began after I tried to run system updates with pacman and got node conflicts, so I uninstalled node and ran my updates, then reinstalled node.

Any ideas?

This is on Manjaro.

Comment: Try to add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to your PATH in `.bashrc`.

Comment: No good. Tried adding it to bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile. I tried adding both `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin` and `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to all of those files. Still can't run npm packages.

Comment: There are (too) many posts to be found for this problem. Try for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found).

Comment: Well I went through all the solutions there and nothing worked, so I gave up and reinstalled Manjaro (was a relatively fresh install anyways). Same problem, but this time when I did the steps [here:](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) (which is an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found) page, for some reason it worked this time.

Comment: Glad that the problem was resolved. I put in an answer below the method that worked for you.

Answer (score 8):

You need get *global* npm prefix be in your PATH variable, which seems is not your case, to learn what is your system npm global prefix path use the "`npm get prefix -g`" command.

"`npm get prefix`" command just prints the local prefix, as the npm documentation said it [1].
In your case npm global prefix, I guess, will be such: 
`/home/alex/.npm-global/bin`

So the simplest solution for problem is to add global npm path, which is returned by "npm get prefix -g" to the PATH, and in case of my guess of it value was correct, you just do this:

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/alex/.npm-global/bin`

Also edit `~/.bashrc file` or it dependant shell scripts where the npm paths are set to theirs values, and add that global path to $PATH environment variable.

Just in case that will not help, 
you can check availability of installed command `fkill` by running:

`which fkill`

or run 
`ls -l /home/alex/.npm-global/bin`

or even search for it there: 
`find /home/alex/.npm* -name fkill`

[1] https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix.html

Answer (score 1):

The post
[Global Node modules not installing correctly. Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found)
contains several solutions that worked for some people.

One
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608206/165358)
worked for the poster, although he first had to again reinstall Manjaro.
This answer summarized the article
[Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally),
and I quote:

> My npm couldn't find global packages as well. I did what Brad Parks
>   suggested: `npm config set prefix /usr/local` Then I got a
>   EACCES permissions error (DON'T USE `sudo npm install -g <package>`)
>   and fixed it through the official npm docs:
>   https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally
>
> 1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations: `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
> 2. Configure npm to use the new directory path: `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
> 3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
> 4. On the command line, update your system variables: `source ~/.profile`
> 5. Then install a package globally and test it! For example: ``` npm install -g awsmobile-cli awsmobile configure